# psycopg in wrong python - Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, psycopg

I'm running Ubuntu. I installed python2.7 and the latest version of Postgresql.

When I installed psycopg, the package showed up in the default Ubuntu version of python instead of the 2.7 version that I want to use.

I tried to reinstall from within the directory I wanted, but it still referenced the other python. When I open the python shell, the version in 2.7.

How can I install psycopg into 2.7?

Thanks for your help.

Joe

```
Stack after installation:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 562, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 544, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 271, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 246, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 236, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 543, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 442, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 303, in _init_posix
    makefile = _get_makefile_filename()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 297, in _get_makefile_filename
    return os.path.join(get_path('platstdlib').replace("/usr/local","/usr",1), "config" + (sys.pydebug and "_d" or ""), "Makefile")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pydebug'
```

Comment: How did you install it? With pip? apt-get?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.apt-get both times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt` works with the Python it installed in the first place.

You need to use [easy_install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) (or, better, [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html)) to install additional libraries to the Python you installed yourself.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like it installed correctly (meaning I find pyscopg2 in my python install (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages) but when I try to compile my django implementation, it claims that there is an 'error loading psycopg module: no module named psycopg'. Is there a way to test to confirm the install is correct (so I can focus on the django issue)?

Comment: @jabs How about running `import psycopg2` in your `python2.7` interpreter? If it doesn't fail, the module must be there. However, it's suspicious that the error message claims _psycopg_, not psycopg2 is not found. Are you sure the Django itself is also installed to the correct Python instance? Hint: When you talk about an error, giving the stack trace never hurts.

Comment: I think I found my problem. I have 2 installs of python2.7. One at /usr/lib/ and the other at /usr/local/lib/

Comment: sorry - not all of that came through...
Anyway - Since I narrowed down the problem I thought I'd clean it up a little and, like a genius, I simply removed the /usr/local/lib installation. I continued to get errors, so I reinstalled python into /usr/lib using:

 wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tgz
 tar xzf Python-2.7.2.tgz
 cd Python-2.7.2
 ./configure --prefix=/usr/lib/python-2.7.2
 make
 make install


This didn't seem to help. Now, when I type in python, I don't get the shell anymore. Rather than screwing it up more, I'll ask again (this time, with a trace below)

Comment: thanks @Helgi

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 562, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 544, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 271, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 246, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 236, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')

Comment: @jabs: Sorry if I'm harsh, but the comments are _not_ for stack traces. It's unreadable. Can you please add their content to your original post, where you can apply formatting? My eyes hurt.

Comment: @Helgi- If you had called me the names you thought of, that would have been harsh. Asking for a formatted trace (telling me that I can edit the original post) was quite helpful and not harsh at all. (I should have seen the 'edit' button, but missed it).

Comment: thanks for helping me understand that ubuntu installs its own version of python and that my apps were being installed into a version I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

Jabs, you're going to have to familiarize yourself with installing and configuring projects yourself. Afterwards, the difference between doing it by hand and using apt-get should be obvious.  It often useful to utilize both a package manager, and installing from source when you want to be on the cutting edge on some things but not others (and it saves a lot of time).  I recommend trying to stick to the package manager for most things.  I noticed a comment where you overwrote the OS installed Python.  This is generally NOT a good idea.

```
./configure --prefix=
```

To learn more use:

```
./configure -h
```

Others environment variables (from configure -h)

```
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor
```

You also may want to look in setup.py when configuring and installing Python.

Also of use for figuring out what's going on and fixing it:

- "Locate a program file in the user's path" - Which executable am I using?

  which python
- "The whereis utility checks the standard binary directories for the speci-
   fied programs, printing out the paths of any it finds." Could possibly show me other installs quickly.

  whereis python
- http://kb.iu.edu/data/acar.html

  echo $PATH

  export PATH=/foo:$PATH
- http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables

  echo $PYTHONPATH
- These also may be of use if using cmake. http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Environment_Variables

  $CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH  $CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH    $CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Hi @Derek. Thanks for all of this info. Just a small clarification...I need more experience on Ubuntu (not necessarily installing Django), since I just installed it yesterday on a vm. That said, this is certainly going to help.

I'll just throw this ubuntu away and create another vm, and **not** delete the OS install. I expect that'd be quicker, and potentially less painful down the road, than finding all of the files and paths that need modified.